# In SQLAlchemy Core, how can I create a table with a column name that differs from its attribute?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a bunch of simple tables like this:

```
newtable = Table("mytable", metadata, Column('user_id', Integer), Column('value', Integer))
```

I know I can access the user_id column like newtable.c.user_id.  However, the name of this column differs among tables, e.g. 'program_id' or 'credit_id'.  I want to be able to create the table such that I can access this first column by a generic key, say 'id', and then use the column attributes to get its actual name, i.e.

```
column_name = newtable.c.id.name
```

and then column_name = 'user_id'.

How do I modify my table creation to do this?  I know how to do it if I'm using declarative_base in the ORM, but I haven't been able to find anything in the docs to do this if I'm just using the Expression Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`key`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.key) parameter:

```
Column('user_id', Integer, key="id")
```

Comment: Aha!  I knew it had to be something simple like that.  Thank you!